# AWUS036ACH, doesn't seem to be injecting packets any more

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I am using a MacBook Pro 2018 and installed the AWUS036ACH Wifi drivers using:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install realtek-rtl88xxau--dkms
```

I ran the OS again and reconnected my device (I use a USB hub due to thunderbolt outlets) and ran a series of tests.

It seems to be working for a sec, had injections, then the light went out and it stopped working since.

I see it is still connected but it doesn't seem to be injecting packets any more.

```
    root@kali:~# iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=18 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.



root@kali:~# airmon-ng check kill

Killing these processes:

  PID Name
  706 wpa_supplicant



root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan0


PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       88XXau      Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
 (monitor mode enabled)



root@kali:~# iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Tx-Power=18 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.


root@kali:~# aireplay-ng -9 wlan0

19:25:43  Trying broadcast probe requests...
19:25:44  Injection is working!
19:25:45  Found 1 AP 

19:25:45  Trying directed probe requests...
19:25:45  A0:04:60:1E:42:B3 - channel: 9 - 'SLOWWOLFJACK'
19:25:46  Ping (min/avg/max): 1.777ms/6.663ms/22.185ms Power: -40.46
19:25:46  26/30:  86%

root@kali:~# airodump-ng wlan   CH 13 ][ Elapsed: 6 s ][ 2019-03-02 19:26                                         

 BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID
 CH 12 ][ Elapsed: 1 min ][ 2019-03-02 19:27                                                       

 BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSIDAR21                

 A0:04:60:1E:42:B3  -41       64       17    0   9  720  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  SLOWWOLFJACK             
 CC:40:D0:7F:D0:C2  -44      102      104    0   4  195  WPA2 CCMP   PSK  NETGEAR21                
                                                                                                    BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Probe                        
                                                                                                    (not associated)   30:8C:FB:05:9E:F6  -33    0 - 1      0        4  NETGEAR21                     
 (not associated)   7C:2E:BD:62:F9:52  -35    0 - 1      0       27  NETGEAR21                      (not associated)   00:00:48:60:CC:77  -41    0 - 1     48       79  NETGEAR77                     
 CC:40:D0:7F:D0:C2  8C:85:90:34:72:10    0    0e- 0e   980       87  NETGEAR21                     
 CC:40:D0:7F:D0:C2  2C:AA:8E:09:BA:AA  -39    0e- 1      3       14                                
 CC:40:D0:7F:D0:C2  64:EB:8C:7B:D4:D7  -45    0 -24      0        3                                
 CC:40:D0:7F:D0:C2  74:81:14:A5:EE:E0  -54    1e-24      0        2                                
 CC:40:D0:7F:D0:C2  2C:AA:8E:09:1A:C1  -55    0e- 1e     0       17                                

root@kali:~# aireplay-ng -9 wlan0
19:27:13  Trying broadcast probe requests...
19:27:15  No Answer...
19:27:15  Found 0 APs

root@kali:~# aireplay-ng -9 wlan0
19:27:18  Trying broadcast probe requests...
19:27:20  No Answer...
19:27:20  Found 0 APs

root@kali:~# aireplay-ng -9 wlan0
19:27:21  Trying broadcast probe requests...
19:27:23  No Answer...
19:27:23  Found 0 APs

root@kali:~# aireplay-ng -9 wlan0
19:27:23  Trying broadcast probe requests...
19:27:25  No Answer...
19:27:25  Found 0 APs

root@kali:~# iwconfig

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.467 GHz  Tx-Power=18 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: It is quite frustrating to finishing reading the question to find out the definition of "wifi not working" is not injecting packets. Edited it for a more meaningful title

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Sorry about that, new to all this technological terms. Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 5):

You are showing us in the first place this wireless chipset is capable of injecting packets. Alas, I bet if this procedure is repeated verbatim (not easy), it will behave the same way.

I assume then the question should be more "why does it stop injecting packets after using `airodump`"?  (and not "Wifi is not working"...sorry for flogging a dead horse for making a point, but keep on reading)

It seems to be well known, that WiFi channels have to be changed manually, when using the Alfa AWUS036ACH WiFi chipset in monitor mode.

So, in this session, from the `iwconfig` output, you started listening to channel 10 (2.457 GHz).

Either there is a step missing, or the BSSID/access point in channel 9 was detected because channel 9 overlaps with the range of channel 10, so the first `aireplay` was successful.

In the next step, `airodump` usage changed channels (several times), and left at exit, `wlan0` monitoring channel 12 (2.467 GHz).

Subsequently, `aireplay` injection tests do not work anymore, because you have no nearby APs working on channel 12.

That can be doubly confirmed with the message "Found 0 APs" and also on your `airodump` output ( 2 APs seen, channels 9 and 4).

TLDR When in monitor mode, `airodump` is coded for changing channels on it's own for scanning. On the contrary, before using `aireplay`, you need to change the channel *manually* in the Wifi chipset, to a channel where there are  APs, when using the AWUS036ACH chipset.

I also got a script to change channels for monitor mode in Ubuntu forums [Can't Change wlan0 Fixed Channel](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1685960)

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script is to change the channel of the wireless card to the one specified, then puts it in monitor mode.
# make sure you uncheck enable wireless in nm-applet before continuing (this script will have no effect otherwise)
# note that if you are using airmon-ng you may want to manually remove all of the monitor devices it has created. (you don't need them)
# to do this run "airmon-ng stop mon0" and if you had more then run "airmon-ng stop mon1" etc.

# this script has undefined consequences if the commands fail (no error checking)
# it would be good idea to run each of the commands listed here separately to make sure they all work before making use of this script
# note that this is just sequence of commands which I would normally run manually on my system, they may not work on yours.
# also you need to run the script as root

#change this to the interface you wish to change
IFACE="wlan0"

ifconfig $IFACE down
iwconfig $IFACE mode managed
ifconfig $IFACE up
iwconfig $IFACE channel $@
ifconfig $IFACE down
iwconfig $IFACE mode monitor
ifconfig $IFACE up
```

PS I advise not (ab)using tools without trying to understand what they are doing.

PPS 2.4GHz Wifi Spectrum standard channels distribution when using 20Mhz channels.

[image: spectrum]

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me TLDR: You are probably much better off using Ubuntu than Kali.